# How to hide the html form and then show the output after clickin on submit button?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Here is my form

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="f1">
            <h3><I>GENERATE HERE !</I></h3>
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-25">
                   <label for="qnum">Select no.of questions:</label>
                    </div>
                     <div class = "col-75"><input type="number" id="qnum" name="que" value="1"  min="1" max="100"></div>
                     <br /><br />
               </div>
             <br />

        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-25">
                <label for="int">Select no. of Integers:</label></div>
                    <div class="col-75">
                       <select name="select" id="int">
                        <option value="2"> 2 </option>
                        <option value="3"> 3 </option>
                        <option value="4"> 4 </option>
                        <option value="5"> 5 </option>
                        <option value="6"> 6 </option>
                        <option value="7"> 7 </option>
                        <option value="8"> 8 </option>
                        <option value="9"> 9 </option>
                        <option value="10"> 10 </option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
      </div>
      <br /> 

       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-25">
             <label for="dig">Select no. of digits:</label></div>
                <div class="col-75">
                  <select name="digits" id="dig">
                   <option value="1"> 1 digit</option>
                   </select>
              </div>
              <br /><br /><br /><br />
        </div>

          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-25"><label>Select operations:</label><br /></div>
              <div class="col-75">
                <input type="checkbox" id="mix" value="all" class="toggle-button"><label>All</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="add" name="operation[]" value="Addition" checked><label>Addition</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="sub" name="operation[]" value="Subtraction"><label>Subtraction</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="mult" name="operation[]" value="Multiplication"><label>Multiplication</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="div" name="operation[]" value="Division"><label>Division</label>
               </div>
                <br /><br />
                <br /><br />
            </div><br />


        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate" id = "gen">
        <button class="button btn1">Play</button><br>
         <br />

 </form>
  </div>

     <script>
      $( '.col-75 .toggle-button' ).click( function () {
          $( '.col-75 input[type="checkbox"]' ).prop('checked', this.checked)
      })
      </script>
```

Below is my php code which is working perfectly. My purpose is to hide the form on clicking play button.and then show the output of my code, how can I do that?

```
 <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if($_POST['digits'] == 1){
            $q = $_POST['que'];
            $rOperators = array('+','-','*','/')
            $previousInt = null;        //Track the previous operand
            $s = $_POST['select'];

            for ($x = 1; $x<=$q; $x++){ //for loop for no. of questions
                $randomOperands = array();
                $randomOperators = array();

                // loop over $i n times
                for ($i = 1; $i <=$s; $i++){ //for loop for no. of integers user entered
                    $nextInt = rand(1, 9); // assign random operand to array slot
                    $randomOperands[] = $nextInt;
                    if($i < $s){   
                        if($previousInt === 0) //No operator after last opearnd
                        {
                            //avoid division-by-zero
                            $randomOperators[] = $rOperators[rand(0, 2)];
                        }else{
                            $randomOperators[] = $rOperators[rand(0, $N-1)];
                        } 
                    }  
                    $previousInt = $nextInt;
                }
                // print array values
                $exp = '';  
                $output_string = " ";
                //Generating the expression
                foreach($randomOperands as $key=>$value1){
                    $exp .=  $value1 . "" ;
                    $output_string .= $value1. "<br>";
                    if(isset($randomOperators[$key])){
                        $exp .=  $randomOperators[$key]  ."";
                        $output_string .= $randomOperators[$key]."<br>";
                    }
                }
                //print expression
                $res = eval("return ($exp);");//evaluate the expression

                echo ("This is Q(".$x."): <br>"), $output_string. "<br>________<br>".$res."<br>";
            }
        }
     }
 ?>
```

The output is generating perfectly fine. I ma just getting trouble in the functionality of hide the form on clicking play button and then show the output , so how can I do that?

Comment: wrap the whole html form in a big `if(!isset($_POST['submit']))`. That way it will either show the form or the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is the solution for your question. if not then feel free to share your feedback with me

```js
$( '.col-75 .toggle-button' ).click( function () {
  $( '.col-75 input[type="checkbox"]' ).prop('checked', this.checked)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" id="f1">
            <h3><I>GENERATE HERE !</I></h3>
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-25">
                   <label for="qnum">Select no.of questions:</label>
                    </div>
                     <div class = "col-75"><input type="number" id="qnum" name="que" value="1"  min="1" max="100"></div>
                     <br /><br />
               </div>
             <br />

        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-25">
                <label for="int">Select no. of Integers:</label></div>
                    <div class="col-75">
                       <select name="select" id="int">
                        <option value="2"> 2 </option>
                        <option value="3"> 3 </option>
                        <option value="4"> 4 </option>
                        <option value="5"> 5 </option>
                        <option value="6"> 6 </option>
                        <option value="7"> 7 </option>
                        <option value="8"> 8 </option>
                        <option value="9"> 9 </option>
                        <option value="10"> 10 </option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
      </div>
      <br /> 

       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-25">
             <label for="dig">Select no. of digits:</label></div>
                <div class="col-75">
                  <select name="digits" id="dig">
                   <option value="1"> 1 digit</option>
                   </select>
              </div>
              <br /><br /><br /><br />
        </div>

          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-25"><label>Select operations:</label><br /></div>
              <div class="col-75">
                <input type="checkbox" id="mix" value="all" class="toggle-button"><label>All</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="add" name="operation[]" value="Addition" checked><label>Addition</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="sub" name="operation[]" value="Subtraction"><label>Subtraction</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="mult" name="operation[]" value="Multiplication"><label>Multiplication</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="div" name="operation[]" value="Division"><label>Division</label>
               </div>
                <br /><br />
                <br /><br />
            </div><br />


        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate" id = "gen">
        <button class="button btn1">Play</button><br>
         <br />

 </form>

 


      <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      ?>
     <script>
      $("form").hide();
       if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
    window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
  }
      </script>
      <a href="javascript:;" onclick="location.reload()">Try again</a>
      <br>
      <?php
        if($_POST['digits'] == 1){
            $q = $_POST['que'];
            $rOperators = array('+','-','*','/');
            $previousInt = null;        //Track the previous operand
            $s = $_POST['select'];

            for ($x = 1; $x<=$q; $x++){ //for loop for no. of questions
                $randomOperands = array();
                $randomOperators = array();

                // loop over $i n times
                for ($i = 1; $i <=$s; $i++){ //for loop for no. of integers user entered
                    $nextInt = rand(1, 9); // assign random operand to array slot
                    $randomOperands[] = $nextInt;
                    if($i < $s){   
                        if($previousInt === 0) //No operator after last opearnd
                        {
                            //avoid division-by-zero
                            $randomOperators[] = $rOperators[rand(0, 2)];
                        }else{
                            $randomOperators[] = $rOperators[rand(0, $N-1)];
                        } 
                    }  
                    $previousInt = $nextInt;
                }
                // print array values
                $exp = '';  
                $output_string = " ";
                //Generating the expression
                foreach($randomOperands as $key=>$value1){
                    $exp .=  $value1 . "" ;
                    $output_string .= $value1. "<br>";
                    if(isset($randomOperators[$key])){
                        $exp .=  $randomOperators[$key]  ."";
                        $output_string .= $randomOperators[$key]."<br>";
                    }
                }
                //print expression
                $res = eval("return ($exp);");//evaluate the expression

                echo ("This is Q(".$x."): <br>"), $output_string. "<br>________<br>".$res."<br>";

            }
        }
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot its working .Actually  I have other 2 issues  I am trying but  I am unable to solve it can you help me ?   1) The first issue is I have two buttons there one is Generate and other is Play , so what I am aiming to do that after filling the form user will click on generate button and after this ,output should be store in an array but not display untill user clicks play.So how can I do that ?

Comment: after submitting the form you can store the values in array and assign that array to session variable. when your will click the second button then get that sesion value and do whatever you want to do with your values..

Comment: or use can also use cookies

Comment: HeyThanks for the suggestion but  Its still not working somehow, I am trying badly for this but still I am unable to fix it, can you show me how can I do it?

Comment: Actally I am beginner in php and I am trying hard but I don't figure out where I went wrong. So it wil be great if you help me in this?

Comment: hey, actually its working now ! I had an issue with variables.

Comment: I don't have any idea how that happened  , but I have marked it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183954/discussion-between-parvej-alam-and-user10625430).